# Register UDAF in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to register a UDAF class (written in Scala or Python) and use it in Spark SQL.
For example:
Mock code

```
// mock code:
class MyUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction{
...
}

spark.udaf.registerJavaFunction("myagg", "MyUDAF",IntegerType)
```

Then I can use the udaf directly within spark sql like following:

```
spark.sql("select myagg(field) from mytable group by something")
```

Spark has only provided spark.udf.registerJavaFunction method to register a UDF class.

Anyone knows how to register a UDAF?

Comment: This blog post develops a UDAF in Java: https://ankithoodablog.wordpress.com/2017/09/07/working-with-spark-udaf-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can just register it using Hive SQL.

```
spark.sql("CREATE FUNCTION myagg AS 'com.mysite.MyUDAF'")
spark.sql("select myagg(field) from mytable group by something")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same for udaf:

```
spark.udf.register("udaf_name", new UdafClass())
```

Then you can use it in Spark SQL.